# Pointing BeautifulSoup towards a certain <tr> class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get BeautifulSoup to grab the numbers in the "Units Sold" column:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import urlopen


html = urlopen('http://www.the-numbers.com/home-market/dvd-sales/2007')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'lxml')
units = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "data"})
print(units)
```

This outputs all the info from the all the columns - so I'm getting close!  How do I narrow it down to just the "Units Sold" column to get the results back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about you iterate over the rows over the table and get the third cell text:

```
for row in soup.select("div#page_filling_chart table tr")[1:]:
    cells = row('td')
    print cells[1].get_text(strip=True), cells[2].get_text(strip=True)
```

Here `div#page_filling_chart table tr` is a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that would match `tr` elements inside `table` element inside a `div` with `id="page_filling_chart"`.

Prints the contents of the "Title" and "Units Sold" columns:

```
Pirates of the Caribbean - At World's End 13,699,490
Transformers 13,251,378
...
Halloween (2007) 1,172,994
Music and Lyrics 1,158,903
```

Comment: thank you so much, @alecxe!  I hadn't even thought of using a CSS selector to do this.  Cheers!